# GPG - How to automatically encrypt files using?

Tags: gnupg

How to automatically encrypt files using? System Linux.

My password : **KHns4621vHJG4**

Option 1 - OK

```
$ gpg -c secret-file.txt

$ Password : **KHns4621vHJG4**
```

Option 2 - How to fix the code to work

```
for file in `ls *.tar.gz`
do
        echo Encrypting ${file}
        gpg -c ???KHns4621vHJG4??? ${file}
done
```

Please advise me.. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You mean this?


pub   rsa2048 2017-12-18 [SC] [expires: 2019-12-18]
      9CB654FA1E1B31F67E1E0A699FF57E3CDB164449
uid           [ultimate] aaaaa <aaaaa@aaaaa.aa>
sub   rsa2048 2017-12-18 [E] [expires: 2019-12-18]

Answer (score 0):

Use the `--passphrase` option:

```
gpg --symmetric --passphrase "**KHns4621vHJG4**" secret-file.txt
```

This works with gpg 1.4.20.
But not with gpg 1.4.18 (it stills asks interactively for a passphrase).

Comment: It does not work, I must always enter the password manually :(